# Highest power of two - javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm using google apps scripts, that works with javascript and I'm writing a piece of code that returns the highest power of two that divides a number, but it doesn't work. Why??

```
function HP2(input) {
  var i = 1;
  while(input % 2^i = 0){
  i++;
  };
  return 2^i;
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `==` in the `while` condition and the `Math.pow` function instead of the xor operator `^`.  Also the return should be `i-1`.

```
function HP2(input) {
  var i = 1;
  while(input % Math.pow(2, i) == 0) {
    i++;
  };
  return Math.pow(2, i-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you stay in the 32-bit range (at least for the divisor) this would be way more performant way:

```
function HP2(input){
    for(var i=0; i<31 && !(input & (1<<i)); ++i);
    return (1<<i)>>>0;
}
```